# Maven won't download because PKIX error from Maven Central

Tags: java, maven, build, certificate, maven-3

I've been working with maven on my machine just fine for months, then I started getting PKIX errors from maven central which prevent me from downloading the appropriate dependencies.

```
> mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.7.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test:testproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10
```

Full debugging output from Maven doesn't appear to offer any additional information.
I created the pom using the generator at [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) with no additional options or dependencies.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>test</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

**What does provide a temporary work around:**

- compile on other machines using the same pom file
- change my settings.xml to point to a private mirror
- add flags to ignore certificate errors.

Though none of these workarounds should be necessary.

**What doesn't seem to work:**

- manually install the certificate into cacerts
- reinstall Java and Maven
- remove the .m2 directory (including settings.xml)

```
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

***Update***
manually specifying the truststore using `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` seems to fix the problem. I'm not sure why Maven isn't finding this file by default and how to fix it.

Comment: The PKIX error is not just for getting the parent POM file. All dependencies coming from maven central are getting the same error.

Comment: Activated TLSv1.2 in JDK 1.8 201 ? If I correctly remember there was a change..try to add to your maven call on command line: `mvn clean package -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise That had no affect, but it is a plausible explanation. The error isn't complaining about the SSLHandshake, but the certificate validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with Maven 3.6.1 or Oracle Java 8_221 installed via Homebrew on Mac. It does not seem to correctly pick up the default truststore (cacerts). Manually specifying the truststore will work.

For fixing my issue, I just changed my MVN_HOME to an old version of 3.6.0 `(97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T14:41:47-04:00)` and installed AdoptOpenJDK8 and everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring your settings.xml to use http instead of https for maven central repository should help

```
<settings>
   .
   .
   .
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>central-no-ssl</id>
        <name>Central without ssl</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
   .
   .
   .
</settings>
```

Comment: Yes, this does work, but doesn't explain or fix why ssl doesn't work on my dev box but it does on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy, you have add the configuration in your maven settings xml

```
<settings>
.
.
    <proxies>

        <proxy>
            <id>mycompany</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <host>10.203.13.45</host>
            <port>8080</port>
            <username>COMPANY\USER</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
            <nonProxyHosts>127.0.0.1|localhost</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>

        <!-- -->
    </proxies>
   .
</settings>
```

Comment: I am not using a proxy. This only affects a single laptop which has connected to multiple networks and had the same problem (no VPNs involved).